# how to navigate from a activity to a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

initially on click of an item in my navigation drawer,I am on a fragment (Question_Fragment),I am checking that is this fragment is called for the first time??? if it is for the first time i need some selections from users,for that i am moving to that activity where user will select options from spinners,when user inputs are done on button click i want to some asynctask(this task will store user inputs into database) then want to return to the fragment(Question_Fragment).on returning of the fragment i want updated contents...

I have tried calling Question_fragment on post execute of my asynktask,

```
Fragment frag = new Question_Fragment();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                //ft.add(R.id.activity_lin, frag);
                ft.replace(R.id.activity_lin, frag);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
```

but on my activities layout,fragment contents are been added...i just simply want to go that fragment.

Comment: Check : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm

Comment: Have you set fragment name in your xml file??

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> for that i am moving to that activity where user will select options from spinners

so while your Question_Fragment is visible (because you say : `I am on a fragment (Question_Fragment)`), you open configuration activity, then after user closes it you want to update your already visible Question_Fragment, but after AsyncTask finishes execution - I assume your AsyncTask is inside activity holding Question_Fragment or in the very Question_Fragment. If yes then you can use fragmentmanager to find you currently visible Question_Fragment and call method on it that will update its content. To achive that specify tag for your fragment.

If on the other hand AsyncTask is inside your configuration activity, then you can update your current Question_Fragment by overriding its onResume and updating its contents there.